# How to trigger change detection / validation in Entity Framework with POCO classes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

We are using the Entity Framework 4.3.1 with POCO classes (no proxies). 
Our User class stores an email address which should be not be used by any other user.
The following test is used to check the validation of this:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void UserEmailNotUniqueTest()
    {
        // arrange
        // - create user one and store in db
        User userOne = TIF.GetUser(model, true);
        // - create user two and store in db
        User userTwo = TIF.GetUserTwo(model, true);

        // act
        // - change user one email to user two email
        userOne.EmailAddress = userTwo.EmailAddress;
        // - save
        model.SaveChanges();
```

The test initialize creates an empty database and hooks it up to the “model” DbContext  decendant. The TIF class creates the test instances of users and stores them in database.  This works, both users are present in the database. 
This validation requires the state of the database to be unchanged, so we have an overridden SaveChanges method so we can pass in serializable transaction:

```
public virtual int SaveChanges(bool commitWhenDone)
    {
            try
            {
                saving = true;
                int result;
                TransactionScope scope;
                using (scope = new TransactionScope( modelTransaction.Get() ))
                {
           //… open connection etc. 
                    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                    IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> validationResults = 
                        GetValidationErrors();
           //… handle the errors
                    result = base.SaveChanges();
```

The test fails as not any change is detected.  No validation code is executed.  Inspecting model.Entity(userOne).State returns “Unchanged”, and yet the CurrentValues contains the proper value i.e. the userOne has the email address of userTwo.

What are we missing?

Comment: Where is your `userOne` instance attached to context? How is your `User` entity mapped?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka The TIF class builds test instances userOne and userTwo, that part is working, at the start of the "act" part of the test both have been stored in the database. Also they are part of the model.Users set.

Comment: @Mark Oreta Thanks for fixing the typos and layout mark

Comment: can it be that user2.EmailAddress is already same as the user1.EmailAddress and therefore the assignment has no effect? Also, how do you check the uniqueness of email addresses? I don't think that the built-in validation (i.e. without implementing custom validation) allows for this.

Comment: @Pawel No this is not the case. The in the CurrentValues contains the new email address, but the state is still "Unchanged"